# Will hypocrites stay in hell eternally?

Tags: quran, tafseer, jannah, jahannam

Many people say all Muslims will go to paradise. even if some muslims ended up in hell, they will eventually go into paradise after their punishment.

But hypocrites are Muslims. And according to my understanding of Surah Al-hashr verse 16-17. Hypocrites will stay in hell forever.

Al-Hashr 59:16

كَمَثَلِ الشَّيْطٰنِ اِذْ قَالَ لِلْاِنْسَانِ اكْفُرْ ۚ فَلَمَّا كَفَرَ قَالَ اِنِّيْ بَرِيْٓءٌ مِّنْكَ اِنِّيْۤ اَخَافُ اللّٰهَ رَبَّ الْعٰلَمِيْنَ

English - Sahih International

**[The hypocrites are] like the example of Satan** when he says to man, "Disbelieve." But when he disbelieves, he says, "Indeed, I am disassociated from you. Indeed, I fear Allah, Lord of the worlds."

Al-Hashr 59:17

فَكَانَ عَاقِبَتَهُمَاۤ اَنَّهُمَا فِي النَّارِ خَالِدَيْنِ فِيْهَا ؕ  وَذٰلِكَ جَزٰٓؤُا الظّٰلِمِيْنَ

So the outcome for **both of them** is that they will be in the Fire, **abiding eternally therein**. And that is the recompense of the wrong-doers.

*So that means not every Muslim will go to paradise and those who are hypocrites will stay in hell eternally?*

Comment: A hypocrite usually is neither a believer nor a Muslim, but a person acting like one of those in public. However there might be different types and degrees of hypocrisy.

Comment: This verse says "when he **disbelieves**" -  he is not a Muslim. Many verses of the Quran clearly declare them as disbelievers, such as [2:8-9](https://legacy.quran.com/2/8-9).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hypocrisy is of various types.

نفاق الأكبر  is related to beliefs. A hypocrite of this type is a disbeliever at heart but pretends to be a Muslim in order to deceive people. It is a type of Kufr and is the one which is mentioned in the Quran. These would remain in hell forever as the Quran explicitly states that in various verses. They are *not* Muslims.

نفاق الأصغر is related to deeds. Such a hypocrite is a Muslim who is not righteous but pretends to be in-front of other people. However he sincerely believes in Allah, the Messenger ﷺ etc. He would not remain in hell forever.

For further information refer to: https://islamqa.info/en/answers/153691/